# Can not use second level derived class as parameter of generic base class type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have an interesting situation where certain things are working but others are not and I'm not sure why.  Below is code that approximates my situation.  I've got a static in a repository that takes a generic type which is implemented by a base type of object.  I then have two levels of derived classes based on that generic type.  The first level of derived class fills out the generic parameters of the base type and works fine, however any class that derives from the class that filled out the generic parameters does not work in place of the base class it is derived from.

```
public class Vehicle<TVehicleType, TStorage>
{
}

public class Car : Vehicle<Car, ParkingLot>
{
}

public class PickupTruck : Car
{
}

public class Dealership <TDrivableVehicle>
{
    public static TDrivableVehicle GetVehicle<TVehicleType, TStorage>(TStorage lot)
         where TDrivableVehicle : Vehicle<TVehicleType, TStorage>, new()
    {
    }
}

public class CarDealership : Dealership<Car>
{
    public static Car GetDrivableVehicle(aCarParkingLot)
    {
        return Dealership.GetDrivableVehicle<Car, CarParkingLot>(aCarParkingLot); <-- Works fine
    }
}

public class PickupTruckDealership : CarDealership
{
    public static PickupTruck GetDrivableVehicle(aCarParkingLot)
    {
        return Dealership.GetDrivableVehicle<PickupTruck, CarParkingLot>(aCarParkingLot); <-- fails
    }
}
```

Certain aspects seem to work correctly in terms of PickupTruck understanding its generic base, but extensions (not shown here) and passing the type to a type parameter specifically do not(the GetDrivableVehicle call).  My guess is that the extension method is related to the type parameter issue since it would need to figure out the type.

Any ideas why this doesn't work and/or what can be done to work around it?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see any extension method on your code. Also, which part is giving you the error, exactly?

Comment: I think I understand some of the problem that you have - but you might want to make sure that the code above compiles only with the errors you highlight.  When I paste this code, there are some fundamental errors; not least the bad parameter specifiers in the last two static methods; and the fact that you're trying to use `Dealership` without passing a type parameter.  Also - you can't put `where` constraints for a class generic parameter on a method within it - it has to go on the type itself. I understand it's an example - but it still really needs to 'work'

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I realize it's an imperfect example, but I was mostly looking for more information about why it wasn't working or what might be a better pattern to use, so I figured that given the complexity of a full blown compilable example, it would at least get the point across.  I think it did from some of the other comments, though sorry that it made it more difficult.

Comment: @Andre - Yeah, sorry, I forgot about putting in the extension method, but the problem was also surfacing on the indicated line.  I believe they are failing for the same reason and there wasn't really a clear way to give the full scope of the extension method.  I'll alter the original question to remove the extension method reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having rewritten your code to a point where I can get it to fail where you say it will - the problem is exactly as Thom Smith says: `PickupTruck` inherits `Car` and therefore is a `Vehicle<Car, ParkingLot>`, not a `Vehicle<PickupTruck, ParkingLot>`.  Also, because of it's generic inheritance it is impossible for it to be anything else other than that.

I know your code is only a boiled down representation of the problem you're having - but if it's close enough, then there might be some useful observations we can make here about the overall architecture.

I'm not against generic bases being aware of their derived counterparts - indeed it's particularly useful for factories; however it almost always instantly rules out any further inheritance.

You're trying to encode far too much information at the type level; and apart from the number of angle brackets we see here it's actually hinted at by the slightly incongruous nature that `Vehicle<TVehicleType, TStorage>` is determining the type of storage that it can be stored within.

To me, that just doesn't make any sense because let's say we have a `ParkingLot` today, but tomorrow we also get a `Hangar` (for cars being stored under cover) - this will require a whole new swathe of vehicle types which are unequal by virtue of the fact that we also have the derived type being passed to the base `Vehicle<TDerived, ...>` - ergo `ParkingLotCar` and `HangarCar` can *never* be equivalent, even if two instances both represent the same make/model etc.

So, anticipating that, you have gone for inheritance where you have a common `Car`, but of course at that point any inheritance is pointless because `Car` is a `Vehicle<Car,...>` so anything derived from it must also be.  Only with Multiple inheritance could that not be the case, but even with that it doesn't get around the whole `ParkingLot` question.

Ask yourself *why* does `Vehicle<,>` need to know about the deriving type?  Is it so you can have a single factory method?  In that case, you should put it into the `Dealership`, or the `ParkingLot` types; not the Vehicle base:

```
public interface IVehicle {}
public interface ICar : IVehicle {} //because pickup trucks share some car traits
public interface IPickup : ICar, IVehicle {}
public interface IStorage {}

public class Car : ICar, IVehicle {}
public class Pickup : IPickup, ICar, IVehicle {}

public class ParkingLot : IStorage {}
public class Hangar : IStorage {}

public class Dealership
{
  public static TVehicle GetVehicle<TVehicle>(IStorage storage)
    where TVehicle : IVehicle, new()
  {

  }
}

//now you can specialise if you really need to

public class CarDealership
{
    public static Car GetVehicle(IStorage storage)
    {
        return Dealership.GetVehicle<Car>(storage);
    }
}

public class PickupDealership
{
    public static Pickup GetVehicle(IStorage storage)
    {
        return Dealership.GetVehicle<Pickup>(storage);
    }
}
```

Now you have the runtime relationships between your vehicle types; allowing different concrete types to share traits such as those on the `ICar` or `IPickup` interfaces; but you've broken the relationship between the vehicle and it's storage so you can get an `IVehicle` from a `FootballPitch` or drive it off the pier to the `RiverBed` if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for that exceptionally well written response.  I think I finally understand the nature of the issue.  Alas, it's a code base I inherited, though the parking lot bit is not quite as scary as it looks as it is a framework driven abstracted data layer, so there is some flexibility to rip it out and replace it with something else so long as it implements the same presentation of the data.  That said, going from the ground up, I'd try to avoid it in the first place.  I think the original reasoning had something to do with some CodeSmith templates, but that predates my time.

Comment: @AJHenderson ah yes. I appreciate this might not hit the sweet spot in terms of your actual issue, and it sounds like you did exactly the right thing in trying to boiling it down to as simple example as you could manage, so kudos to you on that.  CodeSmith templates - hmmm yes - it *was* a great technology till the .Net ORMs became so much more mature :)  Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, we're working on migrating to EF, but have a long way to go.  Trying to split out our functionality to be more app domain specific was one of the first manageable chunks we were able to break out.  I'm sure it will be an on-going process for a while as we have some other gotchas to deal with.

Comment: Also, you hit it plenty well enough, I was having trouble understanding where the issue was entering in and the nature of the way inheritance behaves with the generic was exactly the information I needed.  While it certainly isn't what I wanted to hear, I can understand why the type wouldn't support a derived type because of the type decoration not matching exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it set up, a `PickupTruck` is not a `Vehicle<PickupTruck, CarParkingLot>`, but merely a `Vehicle<Car, CarParkingLot>`. This sort of infinite template recursion can be very confusing to work with. You can solve this particular issue by declaring `PickupTruck : Vehicle<PickupTruck, CarParkingLot>`, by mucking around with co[ntra]variance, or by refactoring your class hierarchy to avoid the confusing pattern.

Comment: This is one example of the sample obscuring the actual purpose a little too much.  To explain in a little more detail, the actual code is loading objects from a database.  The vehicle type is actually the database table the object is being loaded from.  This is an environment where multiple applications are running from the same database and the purpose of this code is to load from the same data layer to one of two or more application specific frameworks.  Because of this, the type truly is common despite the additional level of inheritance.  Car is common, while pickup is app spec functions.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a derived class in place of your base class. This will not work. You should be able to use your BASE class instead of a more derived class, not the other way around. You could convert Car to an interface (ICar) and have PickupTruck implement ICar. That would work.

Read up on contravariance vs covariance. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Comment: I think some care might be in order here - as my comment points out, the code provided doesn't come close to compiling and the problems with it are far more fundamental than issues with contra/covariance.

Comment: True, I agree. There are probably fundamental design flaws.

Comment: That said, @RyanBennett, I think interfaces would indeed be a much better idea

Comment: I've been reading up on contravariance vs covariance because I thought it might be related to that, but I'm having trouble understanding how it applies here.  My understanding is that the Car knows it is a vehicle where the types for the generic are specified.  This first layer works properly when being passed to the method as a type.  I don't understand how the second layer of inheritance breaks it though since the grandchild should have the same type decoration as the child and the child works.  If it was a covariance/contra-variance issue, shouldn't neither inheritance not work either?